# Python tuples and dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to combine strings and dicts as a list of tuples?

Suppose I have a strings

```
s1 = 'Canada'
s2 = 'Norway'
```

I have 2 dicts say

```
dict1 = {'gdp': '10', 'area': '100'} 
dict2 = {'gdp': '20', 'area': '200'}
```

I want to get a list of tuples like

```
[('Canada', {'gdp': '10', 'area': '100'}),
 ('Norway', {'gdp': '20', 'area': '200'})]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried, and what the result was?

Comment: That is a list of tuples. And you can get it by doing `[(s1, dict1), (s2, dict2)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
s1 = 'Canada'
s2 = 'Norway'
dict1 = {'gdp': '10', 'area': '100'} 
dict2 = {'gdp': '20', 'area': '200'}
final_dict = [(a, b) for a, b in zip([s1, s2], [dict1, dict2])]
```

Output:

```
[('Canada', {'gdp': '10', 'area': '100'}), ('Norway', {'gdp': '20', 'area': '200'})]
```

Comment: `[(a, b) for a, b in zip(...)]` ==> `list(zip(...))`

Comment: @Sakshi if this answer helped you, please accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Don't you think using zip and a tuple unpacking is *slightly* over complicating things here for just `4` variables...

Comment: @JoeIddon `zip` and `tuple` are better in the generic cases, when there are more than two corresponding countries and their dictionaries, thus making it simpler for the OP later on.

Comment: Using lots of variable declarations should be discouraged though. But I agree this is slightly more general...

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't define multiple variables and then try and combine these into a `list` consisting of already defined variables as it is not scalable. This is because if you say had ten `sxs` so `s1`, `s2`, `s3` it would be ridiculous! These values must be coming from somewhere so you should just create the list of dictionaries straight from that source, rather than defining intermediary variables.

However, you can achieve what you want with just a simple `list` declaration:

```
final_dict = [(s1, dict1), (s2, dict2)]
```

which gives:

```
[('Canada', {'gdp': '10', 'area': '100'}), ('Norway', {'gdp': '20', 'area': '200'})]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using `map` if you wish to avoid writing any `for` loops in your code:

```
res = list(map(lambda i,j: (i,j), [s1,s2], [dict1, dict2]))
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[('Canada', {'area': '100', 'gdp': '10'}), ('Norway', {'area': '200', 'gdp': '20'})]
```